# Any Language - Port Listener? [UDP]

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I'm looking for any sort of port listener that can look at UDP connections.  The reason is that I'm trying to write a program that looks at what people chat in a game and make responses accordingly. [and hopefully create a server automator for holding tournaments]

I have tried a VB.NET solution, but it would close the connection despite hours of trying to make it do the connection side-by-side.

```
    Imports System.Net
    Imports System.Net.Sockets

    Public Class Form1
        Public Sub Form1_Load() Handles Me.Load
            'Do
            'Dim iReceivingPort As Integer = 58690
            'Creates a UdpClient for reading incoming data. 
            'Dim inEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100"), iReceivingPort)
            'Dim endPoint = New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100"), iReceivingPort) 'System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), iReceivingPort
            'Dim ReceivingClient = New System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient()
            'ReceivingClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = False
            'ReceivingClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, True)
            'ReceivingClient.Client.Bind(inEndPoint)

            Dim ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.100")
            Dim port = 65267

            Dim socket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, True)
            socket.Bind(New IPEndPoint(ip, port))

            'Creates an IPEndPoint to record the IP address and port number of the sender.  
            ' The IPEndPoint will allow you to read datagrams sent from any source. 
            'Dim RemoteIpEndPoint As New System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), iReceivingPort)
            Try

                ' Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host. 
                Dim buffer
                Dim receiveBytes As [Byte]() = socket.Receive(buffer)

                Dim returnData As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes)

                Console.WriteLine(("This is the message you received " + returnData.ToString()))
                'Console.WriteLine(("This message was sent from " + inEndPoint.Address.ToString() + " on their port number " + inEndPoint.Port.ToString()))
            Catch e As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString())
            End Try

            '  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            ' ReceivingClient.Close()
            'Loop

        End Sub 'MyUdpClientCommunicator

    End Class
```

Found a solution, if anybody wants it:  [PYTHON]

```
import socket, struct
# the public network interface
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind(("192.168.1.100", 63578))

while 1:
    # Include IP headers
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
    # receive all packages
    s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)
    # receive a package
    packet, address = s.recvfrom(65565)
    print(packet)
    # disabled promiscuous mode
    s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

The code isn't complete, but it's what I need atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out nMap http://nmap.org/book/nping-man-udp-mode.html

Comment: This is useful, but can I make a macro/communicate with it?

Comment: Not entirely sure. This could be a starting point. [http://nmap.org/book/nse-api.html]. My apologies I know these are not the most useful answers (f.ex. step 1, 2, 3 . . .), but maybe they get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much! ;)  - NVM link is dead

Comment: Will look into it.  Seeya later. :P

Answer (score 1):

Try to learn ruby https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/ then use the socket gem to handle sockets. It's pretty easy to learn.